# Как выделить и сохранить выбранный пункт в ExpandableListView?

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

Дело в том, что у меня `Expandable Group` делится на два, то есть для `groupText` отдельный клик, а для индикатора другой клик, то есть индикатор является `groupItem`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при клике на `groupText(rubricItem)` переходил на другой фрагмент и его `Background` выделялся, и оставался выделенным при переходе назад. Так вот он у меня выделяется таким образом:

```
groupViewHolder.mSelectedGroupItem = (View) convertView.findViewById(R.id.selectedGroupView);
......................
groupViewHolder.groupText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               if (!finalConvertView.isActivated()) {
                        finalConvertView.setActivated(true);
                        groupViewHolder.mSelectedGroupItem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }

        });
.....................
```

он выделяется, но при клике на другой `groupText(rubricItem)` первый так и остается выделенным. И при скролле в разброс почти половина всех `groupText выделяется.

**Вопрос: Как правильно выделить? И при скролле сохранял свое состояние?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это вечный вопрос. Решение таково:

1. Заведите в адаптере переменную (список переменных для множественного выбора) в которой храните позицию выбранного элемента.
2. В методах отрисовки элементов проверяйте содержится ли текущая позиция в числе выбранных и в зависимости от этого отображайте выбранный/невыбранный вид.
3. При нажатии на элемент - добавляйте его позицию в указанный выше список.
4. Предусмотрите способ удаления позиции из списка.
5. Если надо сохранять при поворотах экрана - список из адаптера сохраняйте в активити/фрагменте

Comment: Я не совсем понял 4-пункт, как предусмотреть.?

Comment: @TITAN, ну, например, если элемент нажат, то нажатие будет удалять позицию из списка - иначе добавлять и открывать другой экран. Тут уж от того что вам надо всё зависит

Comment: Спасибо, походу понял, попробую...

Comment: Еще вопрос, их вы имеете ввиду хранить в hashMap?

Comment: @TITAN, да. Например так: `HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>`

Comment: А почему второй параметр В ArrayList, нельзя ли просто в Boolean типа HashMap<Integer, Boolean>?

Comment: @TITAN, всё зависит от ваших нужд. Если вам надо иметь возможно мультиселекта групп и их подгрупп - то надо так. Если только групп - достаточно просто списка с числами. Если выбрать можно только одну группу - то список вообще не нужен - храните только позицию группы. Вы же не говорите что вам надо - вот я вам и даю максимальный вариант

Comment: Мне нужно именно позиции групп... Значит только числа?... Это упрощает... попробую...

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, очень помогло!!!